# git clone with SSH host aliases

Tags: git, github, ssh, continuous-integration

I currently need to achieve the following task: our CI server needs to access a second repository from GitHub with a different SSH (Deploy/Checkout) key than the main project repo (GitHub deploy keys are single-repo only. Two repos => two SSH keys for the same host. Thus the idea about using aliases). However we are currently facing some issues and I'm pretty certain I'm just missing a detail.

Let's say our git repo url is the following:

```
git@gitub.com:myorg/somerepo.git
```

We changed it to:

```
git@gitub-second-account:myorg/somerepo.git
```

Then I adjusted my `.ssh/config` to use the introduced host alias `github-second-account` and map it back to `github.com`:

```
# Default GitHub user
Host github.com
 HostName github.com
 AddKeysToAgent yes
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

# Second account alias
Host gitub-second-account
 HostName github.com
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/second_id_rsa
```

I tested my setup and ran the following:

```
ssh -T git@github-second-account
```

GitHub says all is good and authentication was successful. Great. (Verified via `-vvv` that the correct SSH key is being used.)
But now I go ahead and do the following:

```
git clone git@gitub-second-account:myorg/somerepo.git
```

And get an error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname gitub-second-account: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Yes, there is a warning about the access rights and I double-checked that the assigned SSH key actually has permissions (by checking out with github.com and changing my `.ssh/config` to use that SSH key) and the repo checks out smoothly. I have the nagging feeling that git somehow can't resolve the hostname alias.

Any ideas what's happening? Running `git clone --progress --verbose ...` sadly didn't provide any more information.

Comment: Would the host need to be `github-second-account:myorg` instead?

Comment: If the ssh key works then it’s says to me that the repo is not in the location you think it is.

Comment: Did you solve this? Same problem with the hostname. `ssh -T` reports that I have read access to my bitbucket repo. I am using the clone URL directly from my repo so I know it's correct. I was following a guide from Atlassian: https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2016/04/different-ssh-keys-multiple-bitbucket-accounts/

Comment: typo... you missed the h in github

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have the correct Identity in your SSH-Agent. While it may be specified in your config, I found that if I ran:

```
ssh-add -D
```

and then...

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/theoneiwant
```

This fixed this issue.